# Is $0.121121111112111...$ a transcendental number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

> Let $x=0.121121111112\underbrace{111...1}_{4! \;times}2\underbrace{111...1}_{5! \;times}2\underbrace{111...}_{6! \;times}$. Is it a transcendental number?

As it has no periodic decimal expansion, it is irrational. I tried to prove that it is a Liouville number, i.e.
$$\forall n≥1 \quad \exists p,q \in \Bbb Z, \quad
0<\left|x-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|<\dfrac{1}{q^n}$$
Maybe using rational numbers like $4/33$ or $1/9$ (their decimal expansion is "closed" to the one of $x$). I got stuck, that's why I would like to have some help.

Thank you!

Comment: HINT: Try to prove that $x- 1/9$ is a Liouville number.

Comment: @Crostul: I don't think anyone can add much to your hint (but I am prepared to be wrong). Whenever you feel the time is right you might as well post it as an answer. Your call, of course :-)

Comment: @Crostul: Thank you for your hint. We have $x-1/9=0.02002000..020...$ where the $n$-th $2$ has the $a(n)$-th place with $a(n+1)=a(n)+(n+1)!+1$, so that $a(n)=n - 1 + \sum_{j=0}^n j!$ (OEISA036782). I tried to choose $p_n/q_n$ with $q_n = 10^{a_n}$ (e.g. $p_2=2002,q_2=10^5$), so that $$|x-p_n/q_n|≤10^{1-a_{n+1}}\quad=:A_n$$ should hold. But I wasn't sure how to show $na_n < a_{n+1}-1$, which I need to conclude that $$A_n < q^{-n} \;=\; 10^{-na_n}.$$